# In Visual C#, how do I select data from an access table from a column titled with today's date

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, oledb

I am making an attendance recording project for a parent and toddler group. As part of this I will have an attendance table in my access database called Attendance that will be automatically generated from the names of the children currently in the database. When someone opens the Attendance form and there isn't a column titled with today's date (in the english format) it will make one. Therefore, when I load the data into a dataGridView I want to select the column with today's date as the title. I tried what I thought might work but instead it just added a column to the dataGridView where every record had todays date in it.

```
        loginForm.connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand resetAttendanceTableCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT childName, '" + DateTime.Now.Day + "/" + DateTime.Now.Month + "/" + DateTime.Now.Year + "' FROM Attendance",loginForm.connection);
        OleDbDataAdapter resetAttendanceTableAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(resetAttendanceTableCommand);
        DataTable resetAttendanceDataTable = new DataTable();
        resetAttendanceTableAdapter.Fill(resetAttendanceDataTable);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = resetAttendanceDataTable;
        loginForm.connection.Close();
```

This is my code thus far which has the effect that I outlined above. Is there any way to do this the way I am trying or do I have to try another method?

Comment: You could start using `relationships` instead

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, I got it. I had to remove the 'quote things' and add [square brackets] instead.